# Min value of chart (Chart.js)

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I make a chart with Chart.js it's working but, I search for set a minimum value (for exemple 0) but I can't do it.

My code :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
var NbCanvas = document.getElementById("NbTicketsChart");

Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = "Lato";
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 18;

var densityData = {
    label: 'Nombre de tickets sur la semaine',
    data: [20, 25, 30, 25, 30, 35, 40],
    backgroundColor: '#336ca6'

};
var barChart = new Chart(NbCanvas, {
type: 'bar',
data: {
labels: ["J-1", "J-2", "J-3", "J-4", "J-5", "J-6", "J-7"],
datasets: [densityData],
options:{
        scales: {
            yAxes : [{
                ticks : {
                    max : 100,    
                    min : 0
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}

});
</script>
```

I tried with this :

```
  options:{
    scales: {
        yAxes : [{
            ticks : {
                max : 100,    
                min : 0
            }
        }]
    }
 }
}
```

Thanks for reading !
Arthur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="NbTicketsChart" width="50" height="50"></canvas>
<script>
  var NbCanvas = document.getElementById("NbTicketsChart");

  Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = "Lato";
  Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 18;

  var densityData = {
      label: 'Nombre de tickets sur la semaine',
      data: [20, 25, 30, 25, 30, 35, 40],
      backgroundColor: '#336ca6'

  };
  var barChart = new Chart(NbCanvas.getContext('2d'), {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
    labels: ["J-1", "J-2", "J-3", "J-4", "J-5", "J-6", "J-7"],
    datasets: [densityData]
  }});

  barChart.options.scales.yAxes[0] = {ticks: {min: 0, max: 100, stepValue: 20}}
</script>
```

That was the good solution but doesn't work with char.js 2.8 I use 2.7

Answer (score 1):

This just frustrated me a fair bit. According to the documentation it seems your method should be working. I can only make it work by setting the scale after creating the chart, like below:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="NbTicketsChart" width="50" height="50"></canvas>
<script>
  var NbCanvas = document.getElementById("NbTicketsChart");

  Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = "Lato";
  Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 18;

  var densityData = {
      label: 'Nombre de tickets sur la semaine',
      data: [20, 25, 30, 25, 30, 35, 40],
      backgroundColor: '#336ca6'

  };
  var barChart = new Chart(NbCanvas.getContext('2d'), {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
    labels: ["J-1", "J-2", "J-3", "J-4", "J-5", "J-6", "J-7"],
    datasets: [densityData]
  }});

  barChart.options.scales.yAxes[0] = {ticks: {min: 0, max: 100, stepValue: 20}}
</script>
```

In posting this i've also noticed it doesn't work when the canvas size is 400 by 400. 50 by 50 seems to work...

Comment: Your solution work but if I set the canvas size 1200 by 600, the min value is 20.. But if I delete the width & height it's work

Comment: yeah, I'm not sure if this is a bug with ChartJS

Comment: I'm waiting for someone to have the solution.